# How to jumble up the order of a pointer to an array of strings in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Hi i was given this question and i dont know how to proceed with my attempt.
"Considering the 12 words below. Write a C Program which has functions to do the following:

Jumble the order of words

"Computer" "Science" "is" "my" "favourite" "topic" "and" "I" "learn" "many" "interesting" "things""

my answer failed and i was wondering if you guys could finish my approach or give a better approach do doing so.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
void randomise();
int main(void){
const char *a[12];
a[0] = "Computer";
a[1] = "Science";
a[2] = "is";
a[3] = "my";
a[4] = "favourite";
a[5] = "topic";
a[6] = "and";
a[7] = "I";
a[8] = "learn";
a[9] = "many";
a[10] = "interesting";
a[11] = "things";
randomise();
}
void randomise(){
 int i;

 int lower = 0, upper = 12;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        int num = rand() % 12;
        printf("%d \n", *a[num]);

    }
}
```

Comment: In the `randomise` function, where is `a` declared? Furthermore,`*a[num]` is the same as `a[num][0]` which is the first character in the string pointed to by `a[num]`. You seem to have skipped some chapters in your books.

Comment: It should be `void randomise(void);`

Comment: You actually print words in random (even that is not correct, you print the first char from each word), rather that randomise the words in place (array). Should have been
`int p = rand() % 12;
 int q = rand() % 12;
 SWAP(a[q], a[p]);`

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned it alittle bit up for you.

1. You do not have an access to the `a` array as it is "local" to the main function. You need to pass it to the function and inform how many elements this array has.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void randomise(char **ptr, size_t num);

int main(void)
{
    char *a[12];
    a[0] = "Computer";
    a[1] = "Science";
    a[2] = "is";
    a[3] = "my";
    a[4] = "favourite";
    a[5] = "topic";
    a[6] = "and";
    a[7] = "I";
    a[8] = "learn";
    a[9] = "many";
    a[10] = "interesting";
    a[11] = "things";
    randomise(a, 12);
}

void randomise(char **ptr, size_t num)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
    {
        printf("%s \n", ptr[rand() % num]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You also fixed some of the problems the OP have, but without explaining them. Besides the formatting and indentation, what changes did you make? Why did you make those changes? Please don't assume that the OP will figure this out by him or herself.